# Can IntegerProperty's default value be None in google cloud datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm using Datastore in google cloud.
When I define a kind, can the IntegerProperty's default value be None? Because I wanna query.add_filter('age', '=', None)
e.g.

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    age = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=None)
```

The StringProperty can do that.

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(default=None)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [you can](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#options). All classes inheriting from Property, such as IntegerProperty, can use the `default` property.

Comment: Got it. Thank you, Mangu!

Comment: @RoyYin Hi, would you mind accepting my answer? Thanks :)